# Selecting multiple tables only working in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect four tables. `order_history`, `orders_list`, `infistall_order`, and `delivery_orders`. When I run the code into the table of `order_history`, the results are as what I am expecting. But when I run the code into the webpages, it only selects the value from the table of `order_history`.

*Note: What I mean with running the code into the table of `order_history` is when I enter phpMyAdmin and go to the `order_history` table and run SQL there with the SQL code I have.*

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query
("
    SELECT              orders_history.transaction_id,
                        orders_history.items,
                        orders_history.quantity,
                        orders_history.one_product_price,

                        orders_list.status,
                        orders_list.invoices,
                        orders_list.payment_method,
                        orders_list.order_method,

                        infistall_order.address,

                        delivery_orders.address,
                        delivery_orders.service,
                        delivery_orders.cost,
                        delivery_orders.city

    FROM                orders_history

    LEFT JOIN           orders_list
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = orders_list.transaction_id

    LEFT JOIN           infistall_order
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = infistall_order.transaction_id

    LEFT JOIN           delivery_orders
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = delivery_orders.transaction_id

    WHERE               orders_list.customer_name = 'Klaudia'"      
);
```

Actually I am trying to collect information from all column in all table based on the `transaction_id`.

```
$orders = array();     
$html = '';     
if ($results) {
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items] = array('quantity' => $obj->quantity, 'invoices' => $obj->one_product_price);
    }

    $html .= '<table width="70%"><tr>';
    $html .= '<td>items</td>';
    $html .= '<td>quantity</td>';
    $html .= '<td>one_product_price</td>';
    $html .= '<td>status</td>';
    $html .= '<td>invoices</td>';
    $html .= '<td>payment_method</td>';
    $html .= '<td>order_method</td>';
    $html .= '<td>address</td>';
    $html .= '<td>service</td>';
    $html .= '<td>cost</td>';
    $html .= '<td>city</td></tr>';
    foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
        $html .= '<tbody><tr><td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $order_id . '</td>';
        $row = 1;
        foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
            if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
            $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['items'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['one_product_price'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['invoices'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['payment_method'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['order_method'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['address'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['service'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['cost'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['city'] . '</td>';
            $row++;
        }
        $html .= '</tr><tbody>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
} 
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: What kind of method or how do you show the data into web pages? If you don't mind, please share it with us too.

Comment: @Crazenezz thanks for the respond. I update the question with more information.

Comment: How many data when you try to select from the mysql? And how many data inside the $orders array?

Comment: Thanks. from mysql it gets 12 data from 4 tables, but on the web pages it only shows 4 data from 1 table which it is only from the table of `order_history`.

Comment: Well, your data is already on the track. What is wrong with this code is, your $orders array is using 2D array, that contains `[$obj->transaction_id]` and `[$obj->items]`.

Actually, what are you doing right now will replace the current data that already exist, based on the same key either is `$obj->transaction_id` or `$obj->items`.

Try to change the add process into array into this, and count again the total data inside the $orders:
`$orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items][] = .....;`

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. When I add  `$obj->service, 'service'`, it shows one result from the table of `delivery_orders.service`. Terimakasih. :)

Comment: Glad to help you, already convert my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your loop:

```
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items] = array(
            'quantity' => $obj->quantity, 
            'invoices' => $obj->one_product_price
        );
    }
```

You can change it to:

```
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items][] = array(
            'quantity' => $obj->quantity, 
            'invoices' => $obj->one_product_price
        );
    }
```

It will prevent the data from replacing one to another, the `[]` sign on array is make the array to become dynamic, the key will be count from 0 and will be increment by 1 as you add more data into that array.